# Laravel Pusher Websocket Not Working on HTTPS port 443

Tags: laravel, websocket, broadcast, pusher-js

```
"message": "Pusher error: cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 54.217.244.226: Network is unreachable (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://api-eu.pusher.com/apps/1694685/events....
```

I get an error, when I try using Laravel + Pusher js(with Vue 3). On my local project, it was ok, but after deploying on live server this isn't working

It's my `config/broadcasting.php` file:

'connections' => [

```
    'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
            'host' => env('PUSHER_HOST') ?: 'api-'.env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER', 'mt1').'.pusher.com',
            'port' => env('PUSHER_PORT', 443),
            'scheme' => env('PUSHER_SCHEME', 'https'),
            'encrypted' => true,
            'useTLS' => true,
        ],
        'client_options' => [
            // Guzzle client options: https://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/request-options.html
        ],
    ],
```

Help please

I tried to realize live chat using Webscoket, but an error occured